# How can I extend org symbols table?

Tags: org-mode, utf-8

I use org UTF8 character substitution all the time, for example to go from `\beta` to `β` (enabled with the `org-pretty-entities` variable).

However some standard symbols are missing and I'd like to add them manually. For example, I'd like to map `\|` to `‖`. How can I do that?

Reference: [Org Symbols Table](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-symbols.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`M-x customize-group RET org-entities`, then fill the form under `Org Entities User`. The `name` field is the one which will enable the transformation.

I set `name: Norm` so that `\Norm` transforms to `‖`. I couldn't get it to work for `\|` however.

Comment: how about `\\|`?